# IPsec doesn't read configuration when the tunnel is deleted

Tags: linux-kernel, vpn, ipsec

I've created a tunnel between two sites using IPsec. I've made an error in the configuration, the address of the destination was false, so I deleted this tunnel. But after deleting, ipsec tries to establish the connection with the other site.

What I get from `ipsec statusall`:

```
Connections:
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
   TEST4[1]: CONNECTING, x.x.x.x[%any]...y.y.y.y[%any]
   TEST4[1]: IKE SPIs: eb1655dd8f51750d_i* 0000000000000000_r
   TEST4[1]: Tasks active: IKE_VENDOR IKE_INIT IKE_NATD IKE_CERT_PRE IKE_AUTHENTICATE IKE_CERT_POST IKE_CONFIG CHILD_CREATE IKE_AUTH_LIFETIME
```

and from the log file I get:

```
peer not responding, trying again (52/0)
charon: 04[IKE] initiating IKE_SA TEST4[1] to y.y.y.y
charon: 04[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) ]
charon: 04[NET] sending packet: from x.x.x.x[500] to y.y.y.y[500]
charon: 03[IKE] retransmit 1 of request with message ID 0
charon: 03[NET] sending packet: from x.x.x.x[500] to y.y.y.y[500]
charon: 01[IKE] retransmit 2 of request with message ID 0
charon: 01[NET] sending packet: from x.x.x.x[500] to y.y.y.y[500]
charon: 14[IKE] retransmit 3 of request with message ID 0
charon: 14[NET] sending packet: from x.x.x.x[500] to y.y.y.y[500]
charon: 05[IKE] retransmit 4 of request with message ID 0
charon: 05[NET] sending packet: from x.x.x.x[500] to y.y.y.y[500]
charon: 02[IKE] retransmit 5 of request with message ID 0
charon: 02[NET] sending packet: from x.x.x.x[500] to y.y.y.y[500]
```

How can I reconfigure ipsec to be aware of the new configuration when I delete the tunnel so that it doesn't keep on trying to establish the connection even though there is no tunnel?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I deleted the tunnel"? What exactly did you do? Can you describe the steps in your question?

Comment: I have created the necesary configuration to communicate between tow sites to communicate between them ( keys, certifaction ...) I have deleted every thing , but like `ipsec statusall` mentioned, there is one connection up. Even `ipsec.secrets` file is empty, he try to read from it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply updating the strongSwan configuration files has no effect on the running keying daemon or established IPsec tunnels.

You have to either restart the daemon with `ipsec restart` (which terminates all existing IKE and IPsec Security Associations), or make it aware of the updated configuration with `ipsec update`. Since the latter has no effect on existing connections you'd have to terminate the one started earlier manually with `ipsec down`. In your case `ipsec down TEST4`.

`man ipsec` or the [page about the `ipsec` command](http://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ipseccommand) on the strongSwan wiki provide more information on the available control commands.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But can i reconfigure ipsec parameters, therfore he will be aware automatically that he should stop testing and eliminate the connection.

Comment: Can i do this in `ipsec.conf` file ?

Comment: As I explained, changes in config files such as `ipsec.conf` are not automatically picked up. You have to use `ipsec update` or `restart` to reload the configuration. With `update` existing connections are not modified so you have to terminate those manually with `ipsec down` (also to stop the daemon from retrying if the other peer is not reachable). By the way, if you set `keyingtries` to a fixed number the daemon will automatically stop retrying after a while (you apparently have configured `keyingtries=%forever`).